# Function Will Not Detect String Included In Array Value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a little piece of code in PHP that returns certain key-value pairs based upon if a value contains /includes a specific value: [Code Runnable number 1](https://code.sololearn.com/ws8Ib1l3K2Hc/#)

```php
$example = array('1'=>'if you dont','2'=>'if you like','3'=>'if you know');
$searchword = 'like';
$matches = array_filter($example, function($var) use ($searchword) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); });
print_r($matches);
```

The function works perfectly if the array's value's words are separated, like above. The above code will return an array with all the key-value pairs with a value that includes `$searchword`. However, if the array's value's words aren't separated, like the below, the function will seemingly not detect the word inside the value(that is inside the array), therefore returning a blank array: [Code Runnable number 2](https://code.sololearn.com/wJw0b6oq8D4D/#php)

```
$example = array('1'=>'ifyoudont','2'=>'ifyoulike','3'=>'ifyouknow');
$searchword = 'like';
$matches = array_filter($example, function($var) use ($searchword) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); });
print_r($matches);
```

How could I make the code detect if a value inside an array includes a specific string, even if the value's contents aren't spaced? I have tried searching and many other solutions and nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incidentally, you don't need to use `array_filter`. There's already a function that filters an array based on a pattern.

```
$matches = preg_grep("/$searchword/", $example);
```

But if you aren't going to be using word boundaries, I agree with the other answer that you don't need to use a regular expression at all.

Answer (score 2):

REGEX in this scenario are overkill, instead you can use `strpos`:

```
$matches = array_filter($example, function($var) use ($searchword) { return strpos($var,$searchword) !== FALSE; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the word boundary `\b` from your regex:

```
return preg_match("/$searchword/i")
```